# tablesorter pager recognize the page

Tags: jquery, tablesorter, pager

I have used tablesorter with pager in my website.
The problem is that pager will record the pager number.

When i click to change the pager to p.2
After that, I change the website to other pages.
I come back to that page again. It will show the data in p.2
My expected result should be p.1

It means when i go to other pages and access again to the tablesorter. 
The pager should show p.1.
How can I do that?

In the pager option, I have set to page 1

// starting page of the pager (zero based index)

```
page: 1,
```

Step1: Change page in the jsfiddle(e.g P.8)

Step2: Click run

It stay on the same page after running

Expected result: every time running return back to page 1

Comment: provide code u tried

Comment: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/4mVfu/3572/)
for example, when you change page and run...
What I expected is go back to page 1.

Comment: Ur code perfectly works ! :) whats the problem ?

Comment: the code works! but there is minor problem.
it does not return to initial page even you navigate other pagers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the [documentation](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-pager.html):

> In v2.11, the `savePages` option was added to saves the current page size and number (requires storage script).

So just add the `savePages: false` option to pager configuration:

```
$('table').tablesorterPager({
    [...],
    savePages: false
});
```

Updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6Lroy7u8/)

Comment: +1 @Alan Please click the check to accept this answer.